# multiprocess sub-function does not return any results

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am trying to use concurrency function provided by deco module. The code is working without multiple threads as shown in the answer here:

[Extract specific columns from a given webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137778/extract-specific-columns-from-a-given-webpage)

But the following code does not return any element for `finallist` (it is empty). It returns some results within function scope of "slow" as evident from the print statement. But why does the outer list is empty?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from deco import concurrent, synchronized

finallist=list()
urllist=list()
    
@concurrent
def slow(url):
    #print (url)
    try:
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        mylist=list()
        for anchor in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'col-xs-8'})[:9]: 
            mylist.append(anchor.text)
            urllist.append(url)
        finallist.append(mylist)
        #print (mylist)
        print (finallist)
    except:
        pass

@synchronized
def run():
    finallist=list()
    urllist=list()
    for i in range(10):
        url='https://pythonexpress.in/workshop/'+str(i).zfill(3)
        print (url)
        slow(url)
    slow.wait()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code to work with the module. I fixed two of the [common pitfalls outlined on the deco wiki](https://github.com/alex-sherman/deco/wiki/Common-Pitfalls):

1. Don't use global variables
2. Do everything with square bracket operations: obj[key] = value

Here's the result:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from deco import concurrent, synchronized

N = 10

@concurrent
def slow(url):
    try:
        page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
        mylist=list()
        for anchor in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'col-xs-8'})[:9]: 
            mylist.append(anchor.text)
        return mylist
    except:
        pass

@synchronized
def run():
    finallist=[None] * N
    urllist = ['https://pythonexpress.in/workshop/'+str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(N)]
    for i, url in enumerate(urllist):
        print (url)
        finallist[i] = slow(url)
    return finallist

if __name__ == "__main__":
    finallist = run()
    print(finallist)
```